# Why does the "people reached" always have a ~ sign?

Tags: discussion

We know that the ~ is used before a number to say it's approximate.

But in the case of people reached, the uncertainty comes when 1000 people is passed (after it all numbers has a k to denote kilo or thousand).

Why is the ~ sign used even when the number is exact and three-digits.[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332317/260760 and not sure how updated this is https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/260760 and also this one https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259930/260760

Answer (score 4):

If you hover over the number, it says:

[image]

While you can tell that viewers saw you question (because the page usually opens showing the top), you can't easily tell if they saw an answer you posted. This is why it is an estimate.

Comment: Why doesn't the site let us know how many people have seen an answer, while it is possible for questions.

Comment: Oh, but I have not answered any questions yet. So why still an estimate?

Comment: Probably because question and it's answer(s) are on the same webpage. There aren't separate webpages for them. So only a question _seen_ would automatically and necessarily count the answer as seen as well.

Comment: @Proscionexium There are these for every question just beneath the title: "Asked someday, Modified someday, Viewed X times". Well, why don't answers have these in them? It could be something like this: "Answered someday, modified someday, Viewed X times".

Comment: @SnackExchange With just questions, I don't know why it is an estimate. Maybe the method of monitoring misses some cases, and there is a fudge-factor to catch them. Or it accounts for people click on links with their eyes closed, or with two people looking at the same screen.

Comment: @Karsten Some of these probabilties are impossibe to evaluate.

Comment: @Karsten There are these for every question just beneath the title: "Asked someday, Modified someday, Viewed X times". Well, why don't answers have these in them? It could be something like this: "Answered someday, modified someday, Viewed X times".

Comment: As @Proscionexium tried to explain, you don't know how many looked at your answer if it is one of ten. We don't track the eyes of the viewers, nor do we track the scroll bar (I think).

Comment: @Karsten I'm not speaking about the "people reached" right now. I'm speaking about number of views. Why do question posts have number of views, but answer posts don't? I also don't know who looked at my (or your) questions, but I know how many have looked at them. This sbould be applied to answers too. We don't know who looked at the answer. But we should know how many people have looked.

Comment: @SnackExchange This might be because every answer has a parent question. An answer would be seen only if the concerned question is seen. Note that question views and answer views are equal **by default**. There has to be something _by default_, therefore it is so.

Comment: @Proscionexium What if the number of views is an odd number? If question views and answer views are equal then we have for example 10.5 question views and 10.5 answer views!

Comment: @SnackExchange The way the metric works is that it just add the number of views that you see on the top of the question (the "Viewed by:" metric) on every post that you have contributed to, be it answers or questions. It's an approximate because of this. SE can't track (and doesn't want to be tracking) how people spend their time on the page itself. So if you have one question (viewed by 20 people), and 3 answers (for which the question was viewed 30 times each), you get a people reached score of ~110.

Comment: Perhaps those 30 people have viewed that question a year ago and I just posted an answer on that question yesterday! So any number for "people reached" can be **very** unrealistic.

Comment: @SnackExchange Yup, by that logic you can try to boost your total views by posting new answers to highly viewed posts.

Comment: Also keep in mind that such answer would have to be positively scored.